# In this scenario, are these chances of winning the World Cup equal?

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider the scenario of FIFA 2018 with 4 teams in semi finals: France, Belgium, Croatia, and England. In this scenario every team is equally likely to win the World Cup, so the probability that a given team wins is 1/4.

Now France has qualified for Finals, has their chance increased to 1/2? Or, just like Monty hall problem, is it that every team has 1/3 chance to win world cup?

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: France is $1/2$. England and Crotia are both at $1/4$. Isn't this just common sense?

Comment: It is a) very unreasonable to assume the outcome of football matches can be modeled with uniform probabilities, and b) assuming that unrealistic model, this is so easy to answer that if one needs someone explaining it, I doubt one would truly understand it even with an answer.

Comment: Your use of a) and b), @TorstenSchoeneberg, doesn't make grammatical sense; the "It is" should be able to be read just before the b), like in a list, but it doesn't work in what you wrote.

Comment: You are right, @Shaun. One should read my comment with the "It is" moved after "a)". Anything else you would you like me to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have assumed, but not stated the assumption, that each team in a game has $\frac 12$ chance to win.  Now that France has qualified they only have to win one game to win the cup, so their chance is $\frac 12$.  Whoever they beat now has $0$ chance to win.  The other two teams are in the same position they were-they need to win two games, so have $(\frac 12)^2=\frac 14$ chance to win overall.